# Using Git Bash terminal in VS Code - how to force it to open internally

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

Duplicate: [I asked this on SuperUser without answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1423237/using-git-bash-terminal-in-vs-code-how-to-force-it-to-open-internally)

Using:

- editor: VS Code
- terminal: Git Bash

VS Code offers a shortcut Ctrl+Shift+C to open it externally and a shortcut Ctrl+` (or in my case Ctrl+F1) to open it internally.

In my case it opens it externally with both shortcuts as well as with menu View->Terminal.

I turned Google upside down to the best of my knowledge to find this solution.

I have reinstalled Git from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/).

I checked my VS Code settings (`Code\User\settings.json`) to find a clue, if I accidentally set to force external opening myself.

I know I shouldn't paste an entire file, but maybe you find where the problem in settings.json lies:

```
{
  // Chosen Terminal
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  // Prevent losing aliases, colorization etc. for the Git bash terminal
  // "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
  //     "--login",
  //     "--init-file",
  //     "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\etc\\profile"
  // ],
  // Windows Terminal
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  // Chosen Theme Color and Color Customization
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
      // "statusBar.background": "#666666",
      // "panel.background": "#555555",
      // "sideBar.background": "#444444",
      "tab.activeBackground": "#999999",
      "tab.activeForeground": "#333333"
    }
  },
  // Emmet Customization
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  // Editor Customization
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  // PHP Tooltip Suggestions
  "php.suggest.basic": false,
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe", //for linting
  "php.validate.run": "onSave", //change to onType if need be
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "beautify.language": {
    "js": {
      "type": [
        "javascript",
        "json",
        "jsonc"/*,
        "html"*/
      ],
      "filename": [
        ".jshintrc",
        ".jsbeautifyrc"
      ]
    },
    "css": [
      "css",
      "scss"
    ],
    "html": [
      "htm",
      "html"
    ]
  },
  "beautify.config": {
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "css": {
      "indent_size": 2
    }
  },
  // Git costumization
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "gitDecoration.addedResourceForeground": "#f45342",
    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#3888d8"
  },
  "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "minify.minifyExistingOnSave": true
}
```

If I use Ctrl+Shift+C shortcut, let's say on two different projects, it opens two external terminals just as one would expect.

If I use Ctrl+F1 (default Ctrl+`) shortcut it wants to open them internally so bottom part of VS Code windows looks like this:

[image: Two internally opened "terminals" with split view in VS Code]

And it still opens them externally:

[image: Both opened externally]

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Is `Ctrl+F1` used also for other commands in the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: No. I just checked User Keybindings as well as Default Keybindings and this `{"key": "ctrl+f1", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"}` is the only occurence. Set it to `ctrl+f1` because of Slovenian keyboard. Default shortcut is `ctrl+"backtick"`, but backtick key combination is `AltGr+7` or `Ctrl+Alt+7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems adding `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"` to Settings is the old way and doesn't work as expected.

Delete all lines related to bash from Settings JSON (check User, Workspace and Folder Settings to be sure) and save the file.

Then just open Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and type in

```
Select Default Shell
```

and choose bash from there.

Now all you have to do is restart VS Code and terminal will be running as expected.

For shells that aren't in your %PATH%, see the other answers.

See [the complete Visual Studio Code shell reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

Answer (score 1):

There should be pre existing Terminal profiles already configured so it should be as simple as adding:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
```

to your settings.json